# 'new' not working to create array?

Tags: c++, memory

I am going mental, boiled something down to simple, no matter how or what i try, an array will not work? whats up?

The code is simply a single cpp helloworld from cocos2dx. nothing more,

```
    double *Array = new double[333];
if (Array == nullptr)
    CCLOG("Error: memory could not be allocated");

//initialize it
for( int i = 0; i != 333; ++i){
    Array[i] = 333 - i;

}

for( int i = 0; i != 333; ++i){

    CCLOG("Hi %ld", Array[i] );     
}
```

The loop always prints 0....

Ive tried many loops, test, the array is never array. its ALWAYS just an int, or double, or whatever type of array i try?

Any thoguhts?

VS2012 cocos2dx helloworld stripped to nothing but an array now.
Windows 10

Comment: You probably have the `CCLOG` formatting wrong.

Comment: I agreee with @juanchopanza. Instead of `CCLOG`, try `cout << Array[i] << "\n";` (or `printf ("%ld\n", Array[i]);` if you prefer).

Comment: %d is for integers not doubles.

Comment: With a conforming C++ implementation the condition in `if (Array == nullptr)` will always be `false`, because `new` throws an exception if it fails.

Comment: Instead of a raw pointer and `new`, do consider using `std::vector`. It takes care of the memory management for you, and is resizable and copyable.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are trying to display a double with `%ld` format. `%ld` should be used only for long. IMHO you should :

- either convert `Array[i]` to a long :

  ```
  CCLOG("Hi %ld", (long) Array[i] );
  ```
- or use `%g` format :

  ```
  CCLOG("Hi %g", Array[i] );
  ```

Both methods should give you correct display.

Comment: the formatting was my mistake, i had not noticed to change it after trying, int, double, long, float etc.

The problem..went away after a reboot of my machine?

std::srray people say? 
How would this be used dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

`%ld` is for `long int`. Use `%lf` for `double`.

Answer (score 0):

the formatting was my mistake, i had not noticed to change it after trying, int, double, long, float etc.

The problem..went away after a reboot of my machine?

std::srray? 
How would this be used dynamically / resized?